# R Studio installing packages and functions

Tags: r

I'm trying to use copula on Rmd but am coming across a lot of issues with the formula:

> Error: could not find function "pobs"

For example, I have already installed the packages before by typing this:

```
install.packages("VineCopula")
u <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,1]
v <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,2]
selectedCopula <- BiCopSelect(u,v,familyset=NA)
selectedCopula
```

Code based off this link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/modelling-dependence-with-copulas-in-r/

Comment: Did you load the library before using it? Installing a library doesn't automatically load it in your R session.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't load the `VineCopula` package before using it. `install.packages` is used to install packages, `library` is used to load them into your R session. This is what you should run:

```
library(VineCopula)
u <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,1]
v <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,2]
selectedCopula <- BiCopSelect(u,v,familyset=NA)
selectedCopula
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the library in your code but haven't referenced it hence the functions are not available.

An example of this for reference would be installing an application on your phone; it gets installed but you need to open it in order to use it.

By using `install.packages`, the package was downloaded in your default home folder. You can change that using `install.packages('package_name',lib.loc='path_on_your_system')`.

It is also a good practice to specify the library path before loading it.

```
.libPaths('path_on_your_system')
library(VineCopula)

u <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,1]
v <- pobs(as.matrix(cbind(cree,yahoo)))[,2]
selectedCopula <- BiCopSelect(u,v,familyset=NA)
selectedCopula
```

Let me know if this explanation helps.